# python: reading subprocess output in threads

Tags: python, multithreading, subprocess, buffering

I have an executable that I call using subprocess.Popen. Then, I intend to feed it some data via stdin using a thread that reads its value from a Queue which will later be populated in another thread. The output should be read using the stdout pipe in another thread and again be sorted in a Queue.

As far as I understand from my previous research, using threads with Queue is good practice.

The external executable, unfortunately, will not quickly give me an answer for every line that is piped in, so that simple write, readline cycles are not an option. The executable implements some internal multithreading and I want the output as soon as it becomes available, therefore the additional reader thread.

As an example for testing the executable will just shuffle each line (shuffleline.py):

```
#!/usr/bin/python -u
import sys
from random import shuffle

for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.strip()

    # shuffle line
    line = list(line)
    shuffle(line)
    line = "".join(line)

    sys.stdout.write("%s\n"%(line))
    sys.stdout.flush() # avoid buffers
```

Please note that this is already as unbuffered as possible. Or isn't it? This is my stripped down test program:

```
#!/usr/bin/python -u
import sys
import Queue
import threading
import subprocess

class WriteThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, p_in, source_queue):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.pipe = p_in
        self.source_queue = source_queue

    def run(self):
        while True:
            source = self.source_queue.get()
            print "writing to process: ", repr(source)
            self.pipe.write(source)
            self.pipe.flush()
            self.source_queue.task_done()

class ReadThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, p_out, target_queue):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.pipe = p_out
        self.target_queue = target_queue

    def run(self):
        while True:
            line = self.pipe.readline() # blocking read
            if line == '':
                break
            print "reader read: ", line.rstrip()
            self.target_queue.put(line)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    cmd = ["python", "-u", "./shuffleline.py"] # unbuffered
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, bufsize=0, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

    source_queue = Queue.Queue()
    target_queue = Queue.Queue()

    writer = WriteThread(proc.stdin, source_queue)
    writer.setDaemon(True)
    writer.start()

    reader = ReadThread(proc.stdout, target_queue)
    reader.setDaemon(True)
    reader.start()

    # populate queue
    for i in range(10):
        source_queue.put("string %s\n" %i)
    source_queue.put("")

    print "source_queue empty: ", source_queue.empty()
    print "target_queue empty: ", target_queue.empty()

    import time
    time.sleep(2) # expect some output from reader thread

    source_queue.join() # wait until all items in source_queue are processed
    proc.stdin.close()  # should end the subprocess
    proc.wait()
```

this give the following output (python2.7):

```
writing to process:  'string 0\n'
writing to process:  'string 1\n'
writing to process:  'string 2\n'
writing to process:  'string 3\n'
writing to process:  'string 4\n'
writing to process:  'string 5\n'
writing to process:  'string 6\n'
source_queue empty: writing to process:  'string 7\n'
writing to process:  'string 8\n'
writing to process:  'string 9\n'
writing to process:  ''
 True
target_queue empty:  True
```

then nothing for 2 seconds ...

```
reader read:  rgsn0i t
reader read:  nrg1sti
reader read:  tis n2rg
reader read:  snt gri3
reader read:  nsri4 tg
reader read:  stir5 gn
reader read:   gnri6ts
reader read:   ngrits7
reader read:  8nsrt ig
reader read:  sg9 nitr
```

The interleaving at the beginning is expected. However the output of the subprocess does not appear until *after* the subprocess ends. With more lines piped in I get some output, thus I assume a caching problem in the stdout pipe. According to other questions posted here flushing stdout (in the subprocess) should work, at least on Linux.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do the `subprocess` module, or threads (problematic as they are), or even mixing subprocesses and threads (a *very* bad idea, even worse than using threads to start with, unless you're using the backport of Python 3.2's subprocess module that you can get from [code.google.com/p/python-subprocess32](http://code.google.com/p/python-subprocess32)) or accessing the same things from multiple threads (as your `print` statements do.)

What happens is that your `shuffleline.py` program buffers. Not in output, but in input. Although it isn't very obvious, when you iterate over a fileobject, Python will read in blocks, usually 8k bytes. Since `sys.stdin` is a fileobject, your `for` loop will buffer until EOF or a full block:

```
for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.strip()
    ....
```

If you want to not do this, either use a while loop to call `sys.stdin.readline()` (which returns `''` for EOF):

```
while True:
    line = sys.stdin.readline()
    if not line:
        break
    line = line.strip()
    ...
```

or use the two-argument form of `iter()`, which creates an iterator that calls the first argument until the second argument (the "sentinel") is returned:

```
for line in iter(sys.stdin.readline, ''):
    line = line.strip()
    ...
```

I would also be remiss if I did not suggest not using threads for this, but non-blocking I/O on the subprocess's pipes instead, or even something like `twisted.reactor.spawnProcess` which has lots of ways of hooking processes and other things together as consumers and producers.

Comment: May I ask why the mixture of subprocess and threads is such a terrible approach? It seems more elegant than calling non-blocking I/O over and over again while nothing is happening. Obviously the threads should not access any non-threadsafe datastructures but just reading and writing from or to a Queue seems safe.

Are the changes in the Python3.2 backport important for such a simple case as mine?

Comment: The problem with threads and subprocess specifically is the problem of mixing threads and fork. See http://www.linuxprogrammingblog.com/threads-and-fork-think-twice-before-using-them and other such articles. The Python 3.2 subprocess backport works around those issues. As for threads in general, the main problem is that they're hard to control and debug. For example, you can't kill them from "outside" the thread, so if a thread is stuck in a read or a write there's nothing you can do about it.